# Dependencies across Multiple Systems

Tags: installation, dependencies, rpm, rpm-spec

Imagine a world where I have 4 network connected systems.  System A, B, C, and D.

Now the situation I am trying to figure out how to solve is:
An application I'm installing on System D requires X to be installed on System A and Y to be installed on System B.

We are currently using RPM to handle the application installs since we are using Centos 7.

My question is, is there a way to use RPM to handle this dependency requirement?  Is there a solution to be found with a tool other than RPM?

Answer (score 2):

`rpm` is bound to one system, it cannot cross that bounderay, so **no**.

You could use `ansible` to install the rpm packages on the different systems however.